# How to get lat and long from open street map

Tags: angular5, openstreetmap

I want to get latitude and longitude from open street map in angular when  I clicked on the location, but i can't , how I can do it??I used to get this from google map , but now i want to change it to open street map

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it programmatically, there's a section here

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

you need to know the tile position x/y that you are clicking on (in floating point) and the zoom level (z).

```
n = 2 ^ zoom

lon_deg = xtile / n * 360.0 - 180.0

lat_rad = arctan(sinh(π * (1 - 2 * ytile / n)))

lat_deg = lat_rad * 180.0 / π
```

Source: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames

Answer (score 0):

You can install [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/) place a singular node and in the bottom left corner of the application, there will be a latitude & longitude display.

[image: JOSM LAT/LONG Display Image (Raspberry Pi OS)]